# VueRouter Not Converting To An Anchor Tags

Tags: laravel-5, vue.js, vue-router

I'm learning Laravel 5.5 with Vue js + VueRouter for SPA. I tried to follow this [tutorial](https://www.laracasts.com/series/learn-vue-2-step-by-step/episodes/26).

I followed everything but no luck. I was thinking that the tutorial is not compatible for the latest Laravel version.

This is what I got from inspect element when running `npm run dev`

```
<router-link to="/">Home</router-link>
<router-link to="/works">Works</router-link>
```

**app.js**
import './bootstrap';
import router from './routes';

```
new Vue({
    el: 'app',
    router
});
```

**bootstrap.js**

```
import Vue from 'vue';
import VueRouter from 'vue-router';
import axios from 'axios';

window.Vue = Vue;
Vue.use(VueRouter);
window.axios = axios;

window.axios.defaults.headers.common = {
    'X-Requested-With': 'XMLHttpRequest'
};
```

**routes.js**

```
import VueRouter from 'vue-router';

const routes = [
    {
        path: '/',
        component: require('./views/Home')
    }
];

export default new VueRouter({
    routes
});
```

Comment: Does your `vue-router` work otherwise? How about if you do `this.$router.push('/works')` from a component? Could you post some code how you're setting up the router (the `vue.use()` statement for example).

Comment: @Kano, I believe I don't need to do that. Just placed `router-link` but it doesn't converts into anchor tag

Comment: You believe you won't need to do what? The `this.$router.push()` part or the `Vue.use()` part? The latter is definitely necessary to tell Vue which router you're using as a plugin. The former (`.push()`) was just to test if you've set up the router correctly - it'd help us debug your issue

Comment: the `this.$router.push()` part. take a look at my sample code above. Hope you'll find the culprit or something. Or shall I revert back to Laravel 5.4 version. Hmmm I'm confused honestly

Comment: Tried to do it using Laravel 5.4 and there's no issue.

Comment: Thanks for the example code. You're not really exporting anything under your bootstrap file. Also I'd move `Vue.use(VueRouter` under `routes.js` file and import `Vue` under `app.js` file. Are there no errors in your console about the current setup?

Comment: @Kano, Thanks mate